# In Safari 6, position:fixed stopped working

Tags: html, css, safari, position, css-position

I have been developing a website for the past few weeks, and when I upgraded to Safari 6, `position:fixed` on several divs stopped working. It still works as intended in Chrome 20 and Firefox 14. I have found questions relating to mobile Safari, but nothing on this. Has anyone else experienced a similar issue?

Comment: Sommething is wrong only with your browser

Comment: the reason you haven't found anything about it is that Safari6 has only just been released (and only for Mac OS so far, not Windows), so most people won't have it yet. If it is as big a problem as you're saying it is, it won't be long before other people start noticing.

Comment: I'm having the same problem after upgrading to mountain lion. Going to have to find a solution soon. Our users who upgrade to ML will lose some significant functionality on our site which could hurt us.

Comment: Yes: a position:fixed element will cause the underlying page not to be scrollable. I'm working on a reduction to report to Apple.

Comment: Here's a reduction: https://gist.github.com/3299233

Comment: Yes, I'm seeing it, too. Specifically, I have a block that is position:fixed; and it only redraws in the correct position when I hover over it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `position:static` ? I rememeber reading about this bug in Mobile Safari a ways back.

Answer (score 0):

**HAVING negative z-index values might be the problem!**

I got this problem. Everything fine on safari 5 but on 6 suddenly fixed position divs stopped working.

I was at the time working with background video.

I noticed that placing the background video with a fixed position and a z-index of -100(negative value) made all other fixed divs move on scroll.

So my conclusion was that it is not good to have negative z-index values. I changed it to 1 and all worked fine.